# getUTCDate is not working fine using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get date from JavaScript using `getUTCDate()`.

This is giving me wrong output

```js
var date = new Date();
var startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() - 1, 1);
var endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0);

console.log("startDate " + startDate);

startDate = startDate.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + (startDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + startDate.getUTCDate();

console.log("first Date " + startDate);
```

This gives me `2021-4-31` but it should be `2021-4-1`

Any idea.

Comment: What timezone is your PC?

Comment: i am on GMT+0530

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `startDate` and `endDate` variables are being set to the start and end of the previous month, but in your *local time*.

When you console.log("startDate " + startDate) in node.js, it will output the date in UTC, which will differ from your start and end date by your current UTC offset (5 hours, 30 minutes).

If we format the date using your local timezone, you will see that it is the expected value.

```js
var date = new Date();
var startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() - 1, 1);
var endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0);

// Formats date variable as a local ISO (ish) string.
function formatLocal(dt) {
    let result = dt.getFullYear()  
    result += "-" + (String(dt.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0") )
    result += "-" + (String(dt.getDate()).padStart(2, "0") );
    result += "T" + (String(dt.getHours()).padStart(2, "0") );
    result += ":" + (String(dt.getMinutes()).padStart(2, "0") );
    result += ":" + (String(dt.getSeconds()).padStart(2, "0") );
    return result;
}

console.log("startDate (Local):", formatLocal(startDate))
console.log("endDate (Local):", formatLocal(endDate))
 
console.log("startDate (UTC):", startDate.toISOString())
console.log("endDate (UTC):", endDate.toISOString())
```

Comment: so i am on different time zone will formatLocal work

Comment: Yes, formatLocal will give you the local time in whatever timezone the machine is set to, and you can use Date.toISOString() to show you the time in UTC.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the time zone which seems to be GMT+02:00 on your computer I guess.

> The getUTCDate() method returns the day of the month(from 1 to 31) in
> the specified date according to universal time.

[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate)

```js
const date1 = new Date('April 1, 2021 00:00:00 GMT+02:00');
const date2 = new Date('April 1, 2021 00:00:00 GMT+00:00');


console.log(date1.getUTCDate());
// expected output: 31

console.log(date2.getUTCDate());
// expected output: 1
```

Comment: Then how i can tackle the problem across all the system. if they have different time zone.. Can

Comment: Just call .getUTCMonth() instead of getMonth(), then you have the UTC date on all time zones

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use [moment](https://momentjs.com/) or [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) library. There is a bunch of formation options. I think your problem is with time zone.

Comment: Momentjs itself [says to not use moment for a new project](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)